# Sending XML and Protocol Buffer in a single web socket channel

Tags: xml, angular, websocket, protocol-buffers

I have a single web socket connection with server. The client side code is written in Angular 7. 
Is it wise to have both data formats 'XML and Protocol buffer' over this connection?

If yes, then how to differentiate between both the data formats?

IMO, to parse them, exception based approach has to be taken - like - try parsing with protocol buffer, if it fails then try parsing as XML.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you not use a flag for this? I had a websocket where a binary and a text data (JSON) was being shared. I just had to set a binary flag true or false. may be try that approach

Comment: When I get the binary data.. As for the protocol buffer I directly convert using the generated class from proto schema. So, do you mean to interpret the first byte/boolean of the message and then parse it?

Comment: `how to differentiate between both the data formats?` how did you do this?

Comment: For now, I am trying to parse as a protobuf first. If it fails, then I use `TextDecoder`to get the xml/json and parse it.

Comment: Can you not send a flag?. Rather than parsing the binary with protobuf and then taking the decision, first take the decision and then choose how to parse.